# What wrong? Next.js Image dont work on server

Tags: node.js, next.js, deployment, server, nextjs-image

**Next.js Image does not work on the server, but it works on the localhost.**

One could think about permissions, because I take images from a third-party domain, BUT I load images in a regular img, both on the server and on the localhost correctly.

> The logic is this: I take from the domain side with pictures, images
> of machines and their characteristics into my database. And already
> from the database I reflect them in the Image component. Due to the
> large weight of the image, I applied the sizes attribute.

I don't understand then what the reason may be.  I think you need to configure the reception of images from other servers, somewhere other than next.conf.But then it's strange why it takes the image of a character in a regular img.

> I read here
> https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image-legacy#remote-patterns
>
> My deploy conf: Node + Next.js/Prisma

**Next.js and his < Image /> its work on  localhost but on server i have this:**
[image]

**Network**
[image]

```
<Image
                                    src={car.picture[0]}
                                    alt={car.picture[0]}
                                    layout="fill"
                                    sizes="(max-width: 750px) 50vw,
                                            (max-width: 828px) 40vw,
                                            (max-width: 1080px) 33vw,
                                            20vw"
                                    loading="lazy"
                                />
```

**This is the usual < img />.Its work on server or localhost, but images sizes amazing:**

```
<img
                            loading="lazy"
                            decoding='async'
                            src={car.picture[0]}
                            className="cardImg">
                        </img>
```

**Added a third-party domain with img in next.config.js :**

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};

module.exports = {
  ...nextConfig,
  images: {
    domains: ['mydomaineImg.com'],
  },
};
```

**After upgrade next.js for 12.3.4  my next config :**

```
const text Config = {
  react StrictMode: true,
  ignore Build Errors: true,
  ignore During Builds: true,
}

module.exports = {
  ......next Config,
  
  images: {
    remote Patterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'mydomaineImg.com',
      },
    ],

},
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add two important lines to my docker :

```
 COPY next.config.js ./
    
 COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
```